# why some product has details and the others not in magento 2

Tags: magento2

Hello everyone i am new in Magento 2 ,and i want to know why some product shows the details and the other  no like in the picture :

[image]

> even if they have the same details , is something that i have to customize in the html as below ?:

```
<div class="product options" data-mage-init='{"collapsible":{"openedState": "active", "saveState": false}}'>
                <span data-role="title" class="toggle"><!-- ko i18n: 'See Details' --><!-- /ko --></span>

                <div data-role="content" class="content">
                    <strong class="subtitle"><!-- ko i18n: 'Options Details' --><!-- /ko --></strong>
                    <dl class="product options list">
                        <!-- ko foreach: { data: options, as: 'option' } -->
                        <dt class="label"><!-- ko text: option.label --><!-- /ko --></dt>
                        <dd class="values">
                            <!-- ko if: Array.isArray(option.value) -->
                                <span data-bind="html: option.value.join('<br>')"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                            <!-- ko ifnot: Array.isArray(option.value) -->
                                <span data-bind="html: option.value"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                        </dd>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                    </dl>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is display while you choose any configurable product.
It will show your product selection.
As per your screenshot it is not required for simple product. Which you added in the cart.

Thank you

Comment: can i change the simple product to configurable product by the back office to see the details also for the weight for example , or by changing some condition in the code above please ?